# Как добавить скроллинг невидимой части выпадающего меню?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: Мобильное меню]

При скроллинге прокручивается не меню, а контент который находится под меню. Как исправить? У блока с меню position:fixed.

Comment: Можете вставить сюда код или ссылку на пример, что бы мы могли видеть в чём именно проблема и дать лаконичный ответ

Comment: пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/y8x76w4j/

Comment: [ссылка](http://oecumenical-wines.000webhostapp.com/js/mmm/) не могу разобраться куда оверфлоу написать @Yuri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно ограничить максимальную высоту для выпадающего меню на мобильных устройствах. По необходимости ограничьте действие следующих стилей с помощью `@media`:

```
.wrap_mobile_menu {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 50px); // 100% от высоты экрана - высота верхней плашки
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Здесь на помощь приходят [относительные единицы измерения](https://webref.ru/css/value/size).

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте, что бы меню разворачивало до конца экрана, потом удалите scroll с окна и присвойте его меню. Вот так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.but').click(function() {
    $('.menu').toggle();
    if($('body').hasClass('ns')){
      $('body').removeClass('ns');
    }else{
      $('body').addClass('ns');
    };
  });
});
```

```css
body {height: 2000px;}
body.ns {overflow-y: hidden}

.nav {
  display: block;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px); /* Это что бы сделать до конца экрана */
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Это для скрола */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <button class="but">Открыть меню</button>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Пункт 1</li>
      <li>Пункт 2</li>
      <li>Пункт 3</li>
      <li>Пункт 4</li>
      <li>Пункт 5</li>
      <li>Пункт 6</li>
      <li>Пункт 7</li>
      <li>Пункт 8</li>
      <li>Пункт 9</li>
      <li>Пункт 10</li>
      <li>Пункт 11</li>
      <li>Пункт 12</li>
      <li>Пункт 13</li>
      <li>Пункт 14</li>
      <li>Пункт 15</li>
      <li>Пункт 16</li>
      <li>Пункт 17</li>
      <li>Пункт 18</li>
      <li>Пункт 19</li>
      <li>Пункт 20</li>
      <li>Пункт 21</li>
      <li>Пункт 22</li>
      <li>Пункт 23</li>
      <li>Пункт 24</li>
      <li>Пункт 25</li>
      <li>Пункт 26</li>
      <li>Пункт 27</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что так заморочились)